# Associating metadata with filename_queue in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have setup my reading pipeline as follows: (as explained in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) tutorial)

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, shuffle=True)
image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_png(image_file, channels)
# need to access the file name here!
```

How can I access the name of the file (or some other identifier I can associate with the file) while reading the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this can be tricky to achieve with the current TensorFlow pipelines, but fortunately the [`tf.WholeFileReader`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/WholeFileReader) makes it straightforward: the `key` tensor (returned by `tf.WholeFileReader.read()`) contains the filename of the file whose data is stored in the `image_file` tensor. You can simply use `key` wherever you want to access the filename.